# How to run a console app on a separate window (just like Visual Studio does) using Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

When I run/debug console apps in Visual Studio, the result is shown on a separate window much like cmd. On Intellij IDEA, on the other hand, the result is shown on a integrated console inside the IDE. The latter is not what I want since I'm going to use my console apps when running cmd, and as I develop them I want to be able to see the app's appearance **exactly** as it is going to be when released. Is there any way of debugging/running a console app using Intellij IDEA the same way it happens on Visual Studio?

Comment: You can use an External Tool that will spawn cmd.exe window and run your command there. There is no built-in feature for that.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'll figure out how to use an External Tool. Thank you!

Comment: You can also right click on the Application window title and choose "view mode -> float". Maybe not quite the same thing, but at least the window is undocked and you can place it on the second monitor screen.